# Java Socket close not detected

Tags: java, sockets, connection

I am writing a quick server to test an application. If I close the socket on the client end it does not throw an exception that the socket is closed. I keeps writing 100mb of random data( what it is suppose to do). How can I detect if the client end closed connection?

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.Random;

public class server {

public static void main(String [ ] args){

int size = 1048576 * 100;

String response ="HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n" +
    "Server: server\n" +
    // "Date: Sun, 05 Apr 2009 04:40:08 GMT\n" +
    // "Last-Modified: Tue, 23 May 2006 22:18:19 GMT\n" +
    "Content-Type: application/zip\n" +
    "Content-Length: " + size + " \n" +
    "Connection: keep-alive\n";

try{
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);

    while(true){

    System.out.println( "Listenning..." );
    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

    PrintWriter out = 
        new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader
        (new InputStreamReader( clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine, outputLine;

    System.out.println("-----------Request-----------" );
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {   
        if (inputLine.equals("") == true )
        break;
        System.out.println( inputLine );
    }

    System.out.println("-----------Response-----------" );
    System.out.println( response );
    out.print(response);
    out.print("\r\n");

     //waits for the whole for to finish no exceptions are thrown
    Random rand = new Random();
    for( int i=0 ; i< size ;i++){
        int randnum = rand.nextInt(9);
        out.print( randnum );
    }

    //out.println("test");

    out.close();
    in.close();
    }

}catch( Exception e ) { 
    System.out.println( e.toString() );
}           
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The `PrintWriter` class ignores exceptions thrown by the underlying output stream. As stated in the documentation, you need to actively [check it for errors](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#checkError()).

You might consider using the [`Formatter`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#Formatter(java.lang.Appendable)) class instead of `PrintWriter`. It will help you with the formatting of text like `PrintStream` and `PrintWriter` do (and a lot more), and will also pass along exceptions from the underlying `Appendable` (which should be an `OutputStreamWriter` in this case).